# Why the images not found after deploying react js to github pages?

Tags: reactjs, image, github, vite, github-pages

After deploy my react project to github pages, i've got some error. all the images not displaying.
i've been try some solution like change the path from '../' to './' nothing happen, then i change to '/', it also doesnt show the images. Then i try to moved all the images to public folder. still nothing happen

this is the solution that i've tried

```
<img src="src/assets/img/ramen.jpg" />
<img src="./src/assets/img/ramen.jpg" />
<img src="./public/assets/img/ramen.jpg" />
<img src="/public/assets/img/ramen.jpg" />
<img src="public/assets/img/ramen.jpg" />
<img src="assets/img/ramen.jpg" />
```

this is my repository
https://github.com/callmecua1/Kitsune

Answer (score 0):

If files in this root

public/images/
Use this root

```
'/images/imagename.jpg'
```

But if folder inside src(/src/images) And keep your image in it
Use this root

```
'./images/image-name.jpg'
```